# Dynamic update of gRaphael graph with jquery ui slider value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, graph, svg, graphael

Newbie question: I'm using a jquery ui slider, I want to update a gRaphael chart dynamically as the slider value changes (after a calculation).

problem 1. how do i assign the value returned from the calculation function to the data[] of gRaphael bar graph?

EDIT: As suggested I'm focusing on the first question first, http://jsfiddle.net/anubhabB/VrgcC/30/.

What I want to achieve is a gRaphael barchart dynamically reacting based on the "var sliderVal" of the update(). want to achieve a transition like this ( http://jsfiddle.net/MVwwq/86/ ) to the slide event and dynamic data from slider!!

Comment: This should be two questions, I think (I recommend editing the question to remove the second sub-question and re-asking that separately). Also, would you create a JSFiddle for the first one, so we can see what you've got?